# How I can move my sharepoint 2010 to new 2013 in new domain?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to move my sharepoint 2010 foundation(with Express DB) and upgrade to 2013 foundation in new domain,i already install the new domain and the new 2013 foundation server with stand alone Sql 2012 Database.

Please help me to get the next step to move all my site collections,web application.to work in new 2013(which is already Joined the new domain).

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps needed to upgrade form SP 2010 to SP 2013:

1. Perform the backup of service application databases.
2. Perform the backup of Content Databases.
3. Go to SP 2013 Farm and restore the service and content databases.
4. Give the user performing the upgrade, securityadmin fixed server role on the SQL Server instance.
5. Also give the user db_owner fixed database role on all databases that are to be updated.
6. Create an application pool or use an already existing application pool for services.
7. Create new web application in SP 2013
8. Attach the content databases to web application created in SP 2013.
9. Finally deploy the custom solutions which you may have developed and check if they work properly.

References:

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-from-sharepoint.html

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-sharepoint-2010.html

Answer (score 0):

here is the next steps.
Create Services Applications IF any.
Create Web Application, Apply /deploy the any solution /customization if you have.
Now backup the SP 2010 Content Database and Restore into SP2013 SQL
Attach / Upgrade the DBs to Web Application in SP2013.

here are two UseFul Technet
**SharePoint 2013 Upgrade Process (download)**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30371

**Upgrade databases from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303436.aspx